# Ghost-line artifacts on TToolBar

Tags: delphi, toolbar, delphi-10.1-berlin

`TToolbar` sometimes creates strange mysterious artifacts:

[image]

In this case, I've inserted a `TJvPanel` between two toolbuttons on a `TToolBar` because I needed a **transparent** object to create a distance between these two buttons.

As you can see something creates a mysterious ghost line on the left side of the `TJvPanel`.

How can this ghost-line be avoided?

Here are the project files:

[Unit2.dfm](https://pastebin.com/4cdCDJRS)

[ToolbarArtefact.dpr](https://pastebin.com/cXGwnT3J)

[Unit2.pas](https://pastebin.com/ztmydmcc)

Here are the minimal project sources:

Unit2.dfm:

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 366
  ClientWidth = 606
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -13
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poScreenCenter
  PixelsPerInch = 120
  TextHeight = 16
  object tlbTest: TToolBar
    AlignWithMargins = True
    Left = 0
    Top = 3
    Width = 606
    Margins.Left = 0
    Margins.Right = 0
    Margins.Bottom = 0
    AutoSize = True
    ButtonHeight = 30
    ButtonWidth = 31
    Color = clBtnFace
    Ctl3D = False
    DoubleBuffered = True
    DrawingStyle = dsGradient
    EdgeInner = esNone
    EdgeOuter = esNone
    Flat = False
    Images = ilToolbar
    Indent = 5
    List = True
    ParentColor = False
    ParentDoubleBuffered = False
    TabOrder = 0
    Transparent = False
    object btnAirplane: TToolButton
      Left = 5
      Top = 0
      Hint = 'Show Recent Documents'
      AutoSize = True
      Caption = 'Most recently used'
      Grouped = True
      ImageIndex = 0
      Style = tbsCheck
    end
    object btnAutobus: TToolButton
      Left = 40
      Top = 0
      Hint = 'Show Favorite Documents'
      AutoSize = True
      Caption = 'Favorites'
      Down = True
      Grouped = True
      ImageIndex = 1
      Style = tbsCheck
    end
    object pnlTlbMruFavSep1a: TJvPanel
      Left = 75
      Top = 0
      Width = 16
      Height = 30
      Transparent = True
      FlatBorderColor = clNone
      ArrangeSettings.HorizontalAlignment = asCenter
      BevelEdges = []
      BevelOuter = bvNone
      ParentBackground = False
      TabOrder = 0
    end
    object btnSum: TToolButton
      Left = 91
      Top = 0
      Hint = 'View Thumbnails'
      AutoSize = True
      Caption = 'Thumbnails'
      Down = True
      Grouped = True
      ImageIndex = 2
      Style = tbsCheck
    end
    object RzSpacer1: TRzSpacer
      Left = 126
      Top = 0
      Width = 25
      Height = 30
    end
  end
  object ilToolbar: TImageList
    ColorDepth = cd32Bit
    Height = 24
    Width = 24
    Left = 296
    Top = 192
  end
end
```

ToolbarArtefact.dpr:

```
program ToolbarArtefact;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Unit2.pas:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  JvExExtCtrls, JvExtComponent, JvPanel, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  System.ImageList, Vcl.ImgList, Vcl.ToolWin, JvExControls, JvButton,
  JvTransparentButton, RzPanel;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    tlbTest: TToolBar;
    btnAirplane: TToolButton;
    btnAutobus: TToolButton;
    pnlTlbMruFavSep1a: TJvPanel;
    btnSum: TToolButton;
    ilToolbar: TImageList;
    RzSpacer1: TRzSpacer;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Comment: Looks like a separator.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a separator. But it's a ghost-line.

Comment: Please include a Minimal example here in the question body itself. Off-site resources are not useful here, as they tend to disappear over time. You don't need to include the DPR.

Comment: I've tried this before, but the sum of the file sizes was still too large for SO. I don't know what I could make more minimal as this is already a minimal example.

Comment: @Jerry Ok, I've zipped and encoded the files.

Comment: I don't find it necessary to include images at all in the first place. They're irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: Ok, tomorrow I will add a version without images.

Comment: No. We don't do embedded file attachments here, base64-encoded or not. Code as *text only* in your post, including a text DFM if needed. No zip files, no executables, no encoded binary data. See [ask].

Comment: It's the `TJvPanel`, `pnlTlbMruFavSep1a`, that you have on the toolbar between `btnAutobus` and `btnSum`

Comment: It is clear that the ghost-line is on the TJvPanel. But when you put the very same TJvPanel directly on the form then it has no ghost-line. So it is the TToolBar which CAUSES and CREATES the ghost-line.

Comment: The same ghost-line appears when you use a `TRzSpacer` (or any other TRANSPARENT control) on the `TToolBar`. So it seems that it is the TRANSPARENCY of a control placed on the `TToolBar` which causes `TToolBar` to create the ghost-line.

Comment: Ok, I removed the encodings. Now REMOVE the downvotings!

Comment: Yes, the same ghost-line appears when I add a separator (TToolButton with tbsSeparator style - i.e. Right-Click on the toolbar and click "New Separator"). I assume that's because a separator is practically a TRANSPARENT `TToolButton`. So it could be assumed that every transparent control is considered to be a separator by `TToolBar` where a separator line must be drawn upon. Which is a very stupid assumption.

Comment: Moreover, the separator line is always left-aligned which is another stupid design decision. I wonder what kind of fool has designed this.

Comment: Also, when the toolbuttons have `Grouped = False` and/or `Style = tbsButton` has no influence on the ghost-lines.

Comment: The documentation says: "tbsSeparator - The button appears as an empty space on the toolbar (used to separate other controls)." And: "tbsDivider - The button appears as a vertical line on the toolbar (used to separate other controls)." So either the documentation is wrong or `tbsSeparator` has a bug since the separator line appears on both buttons with `tbsSeparator` and `tbsDivider` where it should appear only on `tbsDivider`, as I understand it.

Comment: As I cannot believe that Microsoft has created such a buggy rubbish - is this a bug in the Embarcadero `TToolBar` implementation of the Windows control?

Comment: Also, the term "separator line" is incorrect, since according to the documentation there should be only a "Divider line" as the "separator" per documented definition is an "empty space" with presumably no line on it.

Comment: I ask the remaining user to REMOVE the downvoting of this question or clearly explain the reason for downvoting!

Comment: WHAT exactly can you not reproduce?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Now, in the comments, you say the same applies for *any* transparent control. I just tried using a `TImage` (since I don't have Jedi), and I can reproduce said behavior in Delphi 10.1 Berlin. I highly suggest removing everything from your question which references your original test, and update it using only components built-in to Delphi.

Comment: ***HINT*** If you just copy the `TToolbar` to clipboard, and paste it in your question, that will be *all* the code we need to reproduce your issue. For me, it produces only 34 lines of code, which we can simply paste into a new form.

Comment: @ Jerry Will do it tomorrow as I need to go to sleep now. Thanks for the hint.